# postgis setup update issue?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, centos7

I installed pgsql and postgis using the instructions on this link, but I used version 11 instead of 9.5, everything went smoothly from a->z
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html

at the last step when doing 'create extension postgis', I get the below error:

ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.5.so": /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.5.so: undefined symbol: geod_polygon_init

any help would be greatly appreciated as been looking all over online and was not able to find how to resolve this, and I'm not too much of a linux expert
(os is centos7)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I found this email in the pgsql-bugs mailing list, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15450-a3638dc978caa94d@postgresql.org

Basically, the PGDG packages for postgis were built incorrectly, and this person rebuilt them manually.

I personally am working on installing postgis from source to resolve this.

Comment: Looks like they are still testing at this point in time, hopefully it gets updated soon. 

I got it finally working by installing postgis 2.5.1 from source, but it took a while to figure it all out. 

The key was ultimately:
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install llvm-toolset-7

then I followed the basic instructions on https://postgis.net/source/

Since I had a very baseline CentOS7 install, I had to install various things in addition such as GCC, geos-devel.x86_64, proj-devel-4.8.0, I believe that's the full list (I installed and uninstalled a million things over the past day).